# How to Apply .nextElementSibling to the next item of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menuitem, itemscontrol

I have a menu that contains sub-items, when I click on them it pops up showing the items. I managed to open the first item, but I can't do the same with the second. I'm trying to use `.nextElementSibling` for this, but I can't. What am I doing wrong ?

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');

dropdownBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
var menuContent = document.querySelector('.drop_container');
    menuContent.classList.toggle("show");
  
})
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}


.drop_container {
   display: none;
   background-color: #017575;
   transition: 0.3s;
   opacity: 0;
}

.drop_container.show {
  display: contents;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.drop_container > .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

<div class="menu-btn">One</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

<div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Did you want both menus to toggle at the same time?

Comment: No, they open separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Collect each `.menu-btn` in a NodeList, then run that through with `.forEach()`.
2. On each iteration reference the `menuContent` as `this.nextElementSibling`.
3. `this` is the `.menu-btn` that user clicked, in order to use `this` do not use an arrow function. If you prefer an arrow function, use the equivalent (in this situation) `e.target` in place of `this`.

```js
const dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const menuContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  menuContent.classList.toggle("show");
}));
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #017575;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.drop_container.show {
  display: contents;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.drop_container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

  <div class="menu-btn">One</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works as I wanted. However, I notice that if I open one, the other does not close automatically. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: That behavior is called mutually exclusivity. In order to do that you must close the one that's currently open then open the one that's clicked. If you do it that way then you can't toggle the same menu open and then close -- basically once one is open then one of them will always be open until a refresh. If you want the option of mutual exclusivity and toggling, then that would involve a whole new question because the solution involves event delegation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338926/how-to-add-mutually-exclusivity-on-toggling-dropdown-menu check it out if you like. Thanks for your help, I am grateful to you for that. Ps: sorry bad english.